# How to restrict the detection of users to be 1?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to develop with Kinect v2 for Windows, in an medical environment that only 1 user should be detected (no intervention from others).

Is there any definition of such value to refer to?

Comment: you simply take the 0 indexed user (which entered first), and ignore any other data.

Comment: Can you post some code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the example here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/743862/Kinect-for-Windows-version-Body-tracking

where the array _bodies gets filled with people data, then simply take the first array element if available.